# Positioning two image links side by side

Tags: html, css

I've tried several different examples found online but now I'm out of ideas...
I'm trying to get two image links centered on the page, side by side.

My current code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div class="home">
<a href="http://www.xxx.net/blog/" id="h1"></a>
<a href="http://www.xxx.net/gallery/" id="h2"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.home a {
    float: left;
}

div.home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

div.home #h1 {
    width:  500px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('header1.jpg');
}

div.home #h1:hover {
    background-image: url('header1hover.jpg');
}

div.home #h2 {
    width:  500px;
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('header2.jpg');
}

div.home #h2:hover {
    background-image: url('header2hover.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add `display : inline` to `a` tags and set the  correct **width**

**Update:**

see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qA8K4/2)

Comment: Correct width is set, 500px for each image. Your demo did not work at all.

Comment: @user2373664 so you must set width for #home div see this update: http://jsfiddle.net/qA8K4/1/

Comment: Definitely getting closer, but that messed up the whole hovering, now both images trigger when you hover one, and it's positioned center horizontally, but vertically it's up top.

Comment: so you can use `top: 25%` for `div.home` or something like this. see this http://jsfiddle.net/qA8K4/2/.

Comment: That sorted out the problem! THanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can put your images in a table row with 2 fields. Then display that table in the center.

Comment: Not looking for kindergarten hacks, even though my coding is at that level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skuntsel: How does this not "provide an answer to the questions?"

Comment: @Jawad Such type of information is usually placed as a comment below a question/answer. We do not evaluate 'brain muscle training' schemes, as you put it. But there is a quality standard as to what is considered a good answer. Or is 'Use some CSS' also an answer in your point of view as 'there is a million ways to achieve the same in CSS' so that OP 'would use his brain muscles' to finalize that idea? Also, we do not advocate offensive phrases in comments!